# Programmatically adding a p:resetInput (tag handler) onto a p:commandButton

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

How do you **programmatically** add a `p:resetInput` to a `p:commandButton`?

```
    <p:commandButton ...>
        ...
        <p:resetInput target=":edit-form" />
    </p:commandButton>
```

I bet the class is `org.primefaces.component.resetinput.ResetInputTagHandler`
but then how do you add a tag handler to a `p:commandButton`? (is this the correct class anyway?)

```
    CommandButton button = new CommandButton();
    ...
    button.getChildren().add( new ResetInputTagHandler( ... ) );
```

1. Where does the tag handler have to go when adding?
2. What's the constructor argument `javax.faces.view.facelets.TagConfig` and where do you get it from?

(all under the assumption I hit the right classes)

Thanks

Comment: This may help you. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/resetInput.jsf

Comment: @Masud: OP is asking how to programmatically (using Java code) add it to the command button, not how to declaratively (using XML code) add it to the command button. Your link does not show any way of doing it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I managed to achieve this by:

```
    CommandButton button = new CommandButton();
    button.setId( "status-change" ); // must have, otherwise no action listeners called!
    button.setIcon( "ui-icon ui-icon-flag" );
    button.setProcess( "@this" );
    button.setUpdate( ":content-form:request-panel :filter-form" );

    ValueExpression valueExpression;

    // some action listener added...

    // programmatically add p:resetInput
    valueExpression = factory.createValueExpression( elContext, ":content-form:request-subpanel", String.class );
    button.addActionListener( new ResetInputActionListener( valueExpression ) );
```

HTH anybody